# Apple Music loved songs

Tags: apple-music, smart-playlist

I tried to create a smart playlist with "Loved" criteria = true, but this smart playlist will only include the loved songs from my library.

1. Is there a way to include also the loved songs from Apple Music that are not in my library?
2. Is there any other way to collect all the loved songs from all my devices into one playlist/album/whatever?

I don't know why Apple makes this so complicated?!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve the Loved smart playlist without adding the song first to your library from my testing.

I have just given a song *Love* on Apple Music and it did not appear in my smart playlist until I added it to my library. Even if it was added to a playlist but not actually to My Music it would not appear.

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. No

Apple Music—for some unexplainable reason—does not enable you to make a playlist of your loved songs. It's a questionable omission, and an easy one to avoid for them, but no, you can not set up a playlist of only loved songs. Instead, just add them to a playlist manually.

Comment: You can make a smart playlist of Loved songs, they just have to be added to your Library.

Comment: Simply stupid if you ask me... So many songs, such a poor UI and poor discovery/playlist options.

Comment: @PrimozRome https://spotify.com

Comment: @PrimozRome https://play.google.com/music

Comment: @JohnRamos Spotify does not work in my country

Comment: @JohnRamos have all my offline music in iTunes and I would not like to use google play. I also don't like google knowing everything about me so I would prefer Apple fixes Apple Music